# How to convert string to double then print the output?

Tags: c++

I'm new to C++ and just started learning earlier today. I'm trying to make a calculator that can take 2 inputs and print an output, just for some practice.

I can't figure out how to convert a string into a double, any suggestions on how to? (Please include sample code!)

This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

string input = "";
string numberOne;
string numberTwo;
double output;

char myChar = {0};

while(true) {
    cout << "Add (A), Subtract (S), Multiply (M), Divide (D):\n> ";
    getline(cin, input);
    if (input.length() == 1) {
        myChar = input[0];
        if (input == "A") {
            cout << "Enter a number to add:\n> ";
            getline(cin, numberOne);
            cout << "Enter a number to add:\n> ";
            getline(cin, numberTwo);
            output = numberOne + numberTwo; //I know that I cannot do this because you can't 
                                           // add two strings and get a double, I just don't 
                                          // know how to make these two strings into doubles (or any other type). Any suggestions?
            cout << "The sum is: " + output << endl;
            output = numberOne + numberTwo
            break;
        }
        if (input == "S") {

        }
        if (input == "M") {

        }
        if (input == "D") {

        }
    }

    cout << "Invalid character, please try again" << endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You should probably use Shreevardhan's suggestion below, but if you must convert a `string` to `double` C++11 provides the `std::stod` function. A `std::stringstream` is another option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of declaring as string and converting to double, declare it as double

```
double numberOne;
double numberTwo;
```

Then, remove getline and input double directly

```
getline(cin, numberOne);
```

to

```
cin >> numberOne;
```

In case you wan't to stick to string, use [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) to convert.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atof/

```
            cout << "Enter a number to add:\n> ";
            getline(cin, numberOne);
            cout << "Enter a number to add:\n> ";
            getline(cin, numberTwo);
            output = atof(numberOne) + atof(numberTwo);
```

Edit: i was wrong, atof is for char array, use http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stof/
instead

thanks @Shreevardhan

```
            #include <string>
            cout << "Enter a number to add:\n> ";
            getline(cin, numberOne);
            cout << "Enter a number to add:\n> ";
            getline(cin, numberTwo);
            output = stof(numberOne) + stof(numberTwo);
```

Comment: What happens when I type that: error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'double atof(const char*)'|

Comment: @MatthewMcHugh [`std::stod`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof)